SafeWallet ApiKit Cancel Previous Proposed Transaction
const sd: SafeTransactionData = {
to: '0x9F1364dcC11d52F17674F10B8Fc2dF795333b079',
safeTxGas:'0x091d48c0a40ea7838cd99dc892b658b2de15f7ecffcfe21d7f64a4d0bed387a9',
baseGas: '0',
gasPrice: '0',
gasToken: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
value: '0', // 1 wei
refundReceiver:'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
data: data as 0x${string},
operation: OperationType.Call,
nonce: 1,
};
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Unprocessable Entity
Error: Unprocessable Entity
at sendRequest (C:\nestjs\aaa\node_modules@safe-global\api-kit\src\utils\httpRequests.ts:58:9)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async broadcastMultiSigTrx (C:\nestjs\aaa\common\helper\evmHelper.ts:621:3)
at async AdminService.testMultiSign (C:\nestjs\aaa\src\admin\admin.service.ts:735:5)
at async AdminController.broadcast (C:\nestjs\aaa\src\admin\admin.controller.ts:298:12)
I get the error when I want to broadcast a new transaction to cancel the previous transaction that proposed. Need some guidances on this issue

Thanks for your question! Could you please add the data field, and precise what do you mean by "cancelling the previous transaction"? Thank you in advance  Best, Louis
